# Non-Disjunct Rectangle Edge Covering for 2D Squares on a Grid

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry, mathematical-optimization

Even though the title sounds complicated, my actual problem should not be too hard to model. However, I have not been able to find a good algorithm to do the following:

I want to cover a set of squares on a grid with a fixed number *n* of rectangles. These rectangles may overlap and they only have to cover the outer edges of my shape.

### Why Not Brute-Force?

The number of different rectangles on a sqare *m* x *m* grid is

[image: (m^2 (1 + m)^2)/4].

Thereby the number of combinations a brute-force-approach would have to try is in

[image: O((m^4)^n)]

That would be *27,680,640,625* combinations for a *10* x *10* grid and only *3* rectangles.

### Example

The initial grid with some squares on it could look like this:

[image: Grid with squares to be covered]

*n* = *1*: The optimal way to cover this shape with a single rectangle would then be:

[image: Grid with squares covered by a single rectangle]

*n* = *2*: The amount of covered empty squares can be reduced using two rectangles like this:

[image: Grid with squares covered by two rectangles]

(Note that the center is now covered by two rectangles)

### Valid Cover

I am looking for a solution that does cover at least all squares that are part of the outer edge, i.e. all filled squares that share an edge on the grid width an empty square.

All squares that are not part of the outer edge of the shape may or may not be covered, the covering rectangles may or may not intersect.

### Target Function

Given a fixed number of covering rectangles *n*, I want to cover all filled squares but minimise the the number of covered empty squares **outside of the shape**. This means that the empty square in the center should not count towards the target function that has to be minimised (I could also fill all the holes before applying the algorithm without it making a difference).

The value of the target function for my example is thereby:

```
n  |  target function
---|-----------------
1  |  11
2  |   3
```

### Additional Constraints

Note that the original set of squares may **not be connected** and that the number of non-connected subshapes may even exceed the number of covering rectangles.

## Alternate Description

To simplify the problem, you could also just work on a transformed version of the input data:

[image]

Then the aim is to **cover all blue squares and minimise the number of covered white squares** using *n* rectangles which may intersect.

Comment: Do all of your target sets have lines of symmetry, like this one?

Comment: @Richard No, they don't.

Comment: This reminds me of the cutting stock and vertex cover problems, both of which are in NP, which implies that you'll need a heuristic, approximation scheme, or some such. I spent a few hours working on a MIP-style solution today, but I'm still learning those techniques and ended up with messy nonlinearities. I've changed the tags to try to bring in folks who are better at that sort of stuff.

Comment: @Richard I know that many of the common vertex & edge cover problems are NP. However, there are corner cases which have algorithms in P. I am really not sure about my specific problem though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't yet thought of a P-class solution, but it did occur to me that this problem may be a good candidate for stochastic solutions.

Notably, there's an easily-defined feasible starting point: just set all of the cover rectangles to the extents of the bounding box of the target squares.

From this initial state, new valid states can be generated by reducing one of the bounds of the cover rectangles and checking to see that all of the target squares are still covered.

Further, the path between any two states is likely to be short (each rectangle can be reduced to its appropriate dimension in *O(√n)* time, where *n* is the number of squares in the bounding box), meaning that it's easy to move around the search space. Though this comes with the caveat that some possible solutions are separated by a narrow path back through the initial state, which means that rerunning the algorithm we're about to develop a few times is probably good.

Given the foregoing, [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is a possible means to address the problem. The following Python script implements it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import numpy as np
import copy
import math
import scipy
import scipy.optimize

#Generate a grid
class Grid:
  def __init__(self,grid_array):
    self.grid    = np.array(grid_array)
    self.width   = len(self.grid[0]) #Use inclusive coordinates
    self.height  = len(self.grid)    #Use inclusive coordinates
    #Convert into a list of cells
    self.cells = {}
    for y in range(len(self.grid)):
      for x in range(len(self.grid[y])):
        self.cells[(x,y)] = self.grid[y][x]
    #Find all cells which are border cells (the ones we need covered)
    self.borders = []
    for c in self.cells:
      for dx in [-1,0,1]:                #Loop through neighbors
        for dy in [-1,0,1]:
          n = (c[0]+dx,c[1]+dy)          #This is the neighbor
          if self.cells[c]==1 and self.cells.get(n, 1)==0: #See if this cell has a neighbor with value 0. Use default return to simplify code
            self.borders.append(c)
    #Ensure grid contains only valid target cells
    self.grid = np.zeros((self.height,self.width))
    for b in self.borders:
      self.grid[b[1],b[0]] = 1
    self.ntarget = np.sum(self.grid)
  def copy(self):
    return self.grid.copy()

#A state is valid if the bounds of each rectangle are inside the bounding box of
#the target squares and all the target squares are covered.
def ValidState(rects):
  #Check bounds
  if not (np.all(0<=rects[0::4]) and np.all(rects[0::4]<g.width)): #x
    return False
  if not (np.all(0<=rects[1::4]) and np.all(rects[1::4]<g.height)): #y
    return False
  if not (np.all(0<=rects[2::4]) and np.all(rects[2::4]<=g.width)): #w
    return False
  if not (np.all(0<=rects[3::4]) and np.all(rects[3::4]<=g.height)): #h
    return False
  fullmask = np.zeros((g.height,g.width))
  for r in range(0,len(rects),4):
    fullmask[rects[r+1]:rects[r+3],rects[r+0]:rects[r+2]] = 1
  return np.sum(fullmask * g.grid)==g.ntarget

#Mutate a randomly chosen bound of a rectangle. Keep trying this until we find a
#mutation that leads to a valid state.
def MutateRects(rects):
  current_state = rects.copy()
  while True:
    rects = current_state.copy()
    c = random.randint(0,len(rects)-1)
    rects[c] += random.randint(-1,1)
    if ValidState(rects):
      return rects

#Determine the score of a state. The score is the sum of the number of times
#each empty space is covered by a rectangle. The best solutions will minimize
#this count.
def EvaluateState(rects):
  score   = 0
  invgrid = -(g.grid-1) #Turn zeros into ones, and ones into zeros
  for r in range(0,len(rects),4):
    mask = np.zeros((g.height,g.width))
    mask[rects[r+1]:rects[r+3],rects[r+0]:rects[r+2]] = 1
    score += np.sum(mask * invgrid)
  return score

#Print the list of rectangles (useful for showing output)
def PrintRects(rects):
  for r in range(0,len(rects),4):
    mask = np.zeros((g.height,g.width))
    mask[rects[r+1]:rects[r+3],rects[r+0]:rects[r+2]] = 1
    print(mask)



#Input grid is here
gridi = [[0,0,1,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,0],
         [1,1,0,1,1],
         [0,1,1,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,0]]

g = Grid(gridi)

#Number of rectangles we wish to solve with
rect_count = 2

#A rectangle is defined as going from (x,y)-(w,h) where (w,h) is an upper bound
#on the array coordinates. This allows efficient manipulation of rectangles as
#numpy arrays
rects = []
for r in range(rect_count):
  rects += [0,0,g.width,g.height]
rects = np.array(rects)

#Might want to run a few times since the initial state is something of a
#bottleneck on moving around the search space
sols = []
for i in range(10):
  #Use simulated annealing to solve the problem
  sols.append(scipy.optimize.basinhopping(
    func      = EvaluateState,
    take_step = MutateRects,
    x0        = rects,
    disp      = True,
    niter     = 3000
  ))

#Get a minimum solution and display it
PrintRects(min(sols, key=lambda x: x['lowest_optimization_result']['fun'])['x'])
```

Here's a display of the algorithm's progress for the the ten runs I specify in my example code above as a function of the number of iterations (I've added some jitter so you can see all of the lines):

[image: Convergence by iteration]

You'll note that most (8/10) of the runs find the minima at 8 early on. Likewise, of the 6/10 runs that find the minima at 5, most of them do so early on. This suggests that it may be better to run many shorter searches rather than a few long searches. Choosing appropriate lengths and numbers of runs will be a matter of experimentation.

Note that `EvaluateState` adds points for *each* time an empty square is covered by a rectangle. This disincentivizes redundant coverage which may be necessary to find a solution or may result in getting to a solution faster. It's pretty common for cost functions to include this sort of thing. Experimenting with a cost function that directly asks for what you want is easy - just replace `EvaluateState` as follows:

```
#Determine the score of a state. The score is the sum of the number of times
#each empty space is covered by a rectangle. The best solutions will minimize
#this count.
def EvaluateState(rects):
  score   = 0
  invgrid = -(g.grid-1) #Turn zeros into ones, and ones into zeros
  mask = np.zeros((g.height,g.width))
  for r in range(0,len(rects),4):
    mask[rects[r+1]:rects[r+3],rects[r+0]:rects[r+2]] = 1
  score += np.sum(mask * invgrid)
  return score
```

Using this cost function does seem to produce better results in this case:

[image: Convergence by iteration with new cost function]

That may be because it provides more transition paths for rectangles between feasible states. But I'd keep the other function in mind if you hit difficulties.

Comment: This seems to be a very nicely engineered heuristic. I will have to test it for larger problems, but this should give "good enough" results in most cases. I thought about implementing a genetic algorithm but simulated annealing actually seems to be more  appropriate for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, @MaximilianKöstler. I've added a chart which may interest you showing the heuristic's progress. I thought about genetic algorithms as well, but decided against them because (a) if crossover is included they become less adept at finding global minima, (b) crossover is likely to generate infeasible states more often than not, and (c) if only mutation is used, other algorithms, such as this, are easier to implement. I am interested to know how this works out for you: please report back! :-)

Comment: Can you add your (I assume) matplotlib-code for the graph to the solution? It would be nice to have for evaluation.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that your `EvaluateState` function adds up the number of covering rectangles for each empty space. I actually just want the *total count* of empty spaces covered (by any number of rectangles) to be minimised, but I can just fix that myself.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler: I actually built the graph in gnuplot, but it should be easy to build a matplotlib code to do what you suggest.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler: Yes, my choice of `EvaluateState` was intentional, as now I explain in my answer. I should have tested other cost functions, but didn't. The direct cost function you suggest actually seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete solution, but some (optimality-preserving-under-certain-conditions) reduction rules:

1. If you want a solution in which no white squares at all are covered, then you can safely merge any adjacent pair of identical rows or columns.  That's because any valid solution for the smaller, merged problem which does not cover any white square can be expanded into a solution for the original problem by "stretching" each rectangle across each merge line in the reverse order that merges were performed -- this won't cause any uncovered white square to become covered, any blue square to become uncovered, or change the number of rectangles required.  Depending on how "curvy" your original image is, this could reduce the size of the input problem by a lot.  (You can still apply this strategy even for solutions that cover white squares -- but the "expanded" solution might then cover more white squares than the original solution did.  Could still be useful as a heuristic.)
2. You can represent any partial solution by turning all cells covered by already-placed rectangles (whether they be originally blue or white) pink; pink cells are cells that may be covered by (further) rectangles at no cost, but do not need to be covered.  If you are looking for a solution in which no white squares at all are covered, you can then apply a strengthened form of rule 1 to shrink the instance: not only can you merge identical adjacent pairs of rows and columns as before, you can first change some pink cells to blue according to the following rule, which may enable more merges to take place.  The rule for two adjacent columns is: If every white cell in column 1 is also white in column 2 and vice versa, then in every row that contains one pink and one blue cell, you can change the pink cell to blue.  (Rationale: Some non-white-cell-covering rectangle must eventually cover the blue cell; this rectangle can be stretched to cover the pink cell too, without covering any new white cell.)  Example:

   ```
   WW         WW         W
   BB         BB         B
   BP   -->   BB   -->   B
   PP         PP         P
   PB         BB         B
   ```
3. You need never consider a rectangle that is a proper subrectangle of a rectangle that covers no white cells.

Some further ideas:

Simply resizing the image to a smaller size, where the new height is an integer factor of the original height and similarly for the width, and a cell is blue iff any cell in the corresponding block of cells in the original image was blue, should give a good approximate subproblem that is easier to solve.  (Pad the original image with white cells if necessary.)  After solving this smaller problem and reexpanding the solution up to the original size, you may be able to trim further rows or columns off the edges of some rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I agree on the simplifications you suggest. However, I do not think that just reducing the complexity like this will ultimately lead to a problem which is feasible to compute. Even if I could eliminate 99.999% of all cases to consider, it would still take a billion years to find the optimal solution for a slightly larger problem than the example I gave. If there is no 'smart' solution for a related mathematical problem, I will just have to use a heuristic. Your suggestions are much appreciated for that.

Comment: You're welcome :)  I think you could probably get quite far using branch-and-bound for an exact solution under the no-covered-white-squares condition, if at each decision point you choose the blue cell that could be covered by the smallest number of white-cell-avoiding maximal rectangles (there may be several such cells; pick any one), and try placing each of these maximal rectangles in turn.  Also I've now convinced myself that merging adjacent identical rows or columns preserves optimality *even when we are allowed to cover some white cells*.

Comment: In fact, B&B would work even for solutions that cover some white squares -- instead of considering only maximal rectangles that cover no white squares, you would need to consider the larger set of rectangles that (a) are not contained in any larger blue-and-pink-only rectangle and (b) do not cause the total number of covered white cells in the partial solution so far to exceed the number in the incumbent (best-so-far) full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different problem that I'd like to propose:

say you have three isolated squares what are the possibilities:

one rectangle covering all three

two rectangles, with 3 possibilities covering 2 +1

and three rectangles covering one each

so the order is Sum_i n_choose_i

much smaller than your order

polynomial in any case on n rather than exponential.

Then you can trim down your solution (which are conflicting by the way: which is better fewer rectangles or lesser empty cell, but you can cover that)

Comment: Firstly, regarding the last line of your solution: My aim is to get the best possible cover (regarding my target function) for an arbitrary but FIXED number of rectangles *n*. So *n* is not a variable during the optimisation. It is chosen beforehand.
Secondly, your solution is not correct. You need the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) if you use combinatorics. For 100 sqares and three rectangles that is around 10^47.